# How can I parse a weekday and time object to the next logical date from today?

Tags: java

I have a date in the string that looks like `MON 07:15`. I'm trying to parse this to a `Date` using this snippet of code:

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("E kk:mm").parse("MON 07:15"));
```

Using the above code, prints a date that reads:

```
Mon Jan 05 07:15:00 EET 1970
```

I'd like the parse the date string to the next upcoming date. At the time of posting, my local date and time is `Fri Aug 08 11:45:00 EEST 2014` and the next Monday will be on the 11th so the resultant date that I'm looking for is `Mon Aug 11 07:15:00 EEST 2014`. How can I parse this?

---

The day and time object that I'll be parsing will always be in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would separate parsing from everything else.

Parse the value as you're already doing, which gives you a date in the wrong year.

From that, take the time of day and the day of week - those are the important things. You can throw everything else away.

Next, take the *current* date and time, and perform whatever operations you need to in order to get to the right date/time. You should consider:

- What time zone are you interested in?
- If the current time is 06:00 on a Monday and you've been asked for 07:15 on a Monday, does that mean today or next Monday?
- If the current time is 08:00 on a Monday and you've been asked for 07:15 on a Monday, does that mean today or next Monday?

By separating out the parsing from the computations, you can make the testing simpler two: test each of the operations separately. I'd advise using a clock abstraction of some kind to indicate "an object which can get you the current instant in time" - that way you can test all kinds of combinations of "desired day/time" and "current day/time".

Ideally, use `java.time` from Java 8 or [Joda Time](http://joda.org/joda-time) - both are *much* nicer than the `java.util.*` API.

Comment: I made an edit to my question as I forgot to mention that the day and time object that I'll be parsing will always be in the future.

Comment: @MridangAgarwalla: The value you're parsing doesn't specify a date at all - it's not in the future or in the past... but even so, that doesn't necessarily answer the questions in my answer. Anyway, that's up to you to work out - separate out the parsing from the computation, and if you have problems with either of those, you can ask a more specific question which is just about one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking something like following?

```
 DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("E kk:mm");
 Date date = df.parse("MON 07:15");
 Date today = new Date();
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
 calendar.setTime(today);
 calendar1.setTime(date);
 if (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == calendar1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)) {
       String time = df.format(today);
       Date t1 = df.parse(time);
        if (t1.before(date)) {
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, calendar1.get(Calendar.HOUR));
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, calendar1.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
        } else {
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, calendar1.get(Calendar.HOUR));
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, calendar1.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
        }
    } else {
        int toDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        int givenDay = calendar1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        int count = 7 - toDay + givenDay;
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, count);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, calendar1.get(Calendar.HOUR));
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, calendar1.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
        System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
    }
```

Out put:

```
   Mon Aug 11 07:15:00 IST 2014
```

Leave me a comment telling me whether I got your question correct.

Answer (score 0):

This answer addresses the second part, getting the next logical date from today.

## Avoid .Date/.Calendar

The java.util.Date & .Calendar classes bundled with Java are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them.

## Joda-Time or java.time

I suggest learning how to use a sophisticated date-time library. In Java that means either:

- [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)
- [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) (built into Java 8, inspired by Joda-Time).

## Time Zone

The time zone is crucial in determining the day and day-of-week. Use [proper time zone names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), never the 3 or 4 letter codes.

If you ignore time zone, the JVM’s current default time zone will be applied implicitly. This means different outputs when moving your app from one machine to another, or when a sys admin changes the time zone of host machine, or when any Java code in any thread of any app within the same JVM decides to call [`setDefault`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault-java.util.TimeZone-) *even during* your app‘s execution.

## Example Code To Get Next Day-Of-Week

Here is example code using Joda-Time 2.7.

Get the time zone you desire/expect. If working in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), use the constant `DateTimeZone.UTC`.

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" );
```

Get the date-time value you need. Here I am using the current moment.

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now( zone );
```

Specify the future day-of-week you want. Note that Joda-Time uses the sensible # 1 for first day of week, rather than zero-based counting found in java.util.Calendar. First day of week is Monday, per international norms and standards (not Sunday as is common in United States).

```
int dayOfWeek = DateTimeConstants.SATURDAY;
```

The `withDayOfWeek` command may go back in time. So we use a [ternary operator (`?:`)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) to make sure we go forwards in time by adding a week as needed.

```
DateTime future = ( dateTime.getDayOfWeek() < dayOfWeek )
        ? dateTime.withDayOfWeek( dayOfWeek )
        : dateTime.plusWeeks( 1 ).withDayOfWeek( dayOfWeek );
```

You may want to adjust the time-of-day to the first moment of the day to emphasize the focus on the day rather than a particular moment within the day.

```
future = future.withTimeAtStartOfDay(); // Adjust time-of-day to first moment of the day to stress the focus on the entire day rather than a specific moment within the day. Or use `LocalDate` class.
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "Next day # " + dayOfWeek + " after " + dateTime + " is " + future );
```

When run.

```
Next day # 6 after 2015-04-18T16:03:36.146-04:00 is 2015-04-25T00:00:00.000-04:00
```